# How to make parallel outbound calls

Tags: java, parallel-processing, mule, mule-flow

My use case requires to enrich my input with smne data and send it to an outbound endpoint.

The data for enriching is obtained by making calls to two web-services and then extract the data from the reply.
This extracted data is enriched into my input XML and sent to an outbound endpoint.

The two web-service calls that I need to make needs to be parallel, as they don't have dependency on another. This way I could save my processing time.

Please suggest how I could achieve this parallel processing in a flow in Mule.

Note: I have tried using ALL flow control, but it seems that is calling the web-services (sub-flows) sequentially.

Given below is my abstract flow.

```
<flow name="mainFlow">
    <inbound-endpoint> .....

    <some validation>

    <setting some flow variables>

    <!-- Now make calls to the sub-flows which has some processing of the input and make some web-service calls -->
    <all>
        <flow-ref name="myFlow1" />
        <flow-ref name="myFlow2" />
        <flow-ref name="myFlow3" />
    </all>

    <enrich the input with the data obtained from the output of the above three flows>

    <outbound-endpoint>
</flow>



<flow name="myFlow1">
    <some transformer to transform the payload provided >

    < the tran sformed payload is passed as input to the web-service call>

    <http:outbound-endpoint ...>

    <transform the reply from the web-service call>
</flow>



<flow name="myFlow2">
    <some transformer to transform the payload provided >

    < the tran sformed payload is passed as input to the web-service call>

    <http:outbound-endpoint ...>

    <transform the reply from the web-service call>
</flow>



<flow name="myFlow3">
    <some transformer to transform the payload provided to it>

    < the tran sformed payload is passed as input to the web-service call>

    <http:outbound-endpoint ...>

    <transform the reply from the web-service call>
</flow>
```

Comment: Wouldn't using a fork-join pattern work for you - with the WS calls between the fork and join?

Comment: Thanks David Dossot for your editing... :)

Comment: In my case I am using ALL flow control to send the input to two sub-flows. I am not sure how I can use a fork-join pattern for web-services calls. Also I am not directly calling the "outbound end points". I need to make a call to the sub flows where some processing on the input message happens before the call to the web-service is made. Please advise if I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple configuration that shows one way to make a fork/join with two HTTP outbound endpoints. To add a third endpoint, set `MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE` to `3` and the `MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE` of the third `async flow-ref` to `3`.

```
<flow name="fork">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="fork.in" />
    <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE"
        value="2" />
    <all enableCorrelation="IF_NOT_SET">
        <async>
            <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE"
                value="1" />
            <flow-ref name="parallel1" />
        </async>
        <async>
            <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE"
                value="2" />
            <flow-ref name="parallel2" />
        </async>
    </all>
</flow>

<sub-flow name="parallel1">
    <logger level="INFO" message="parallel1: processing started" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="..."
        exchange-pattern="request-response" />
    <logger level="INFO" message="parallel1: processing finished" />
    <flow-ref name="join" />
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="parallel2">
    <logger level="INFO" message="parallel2: processing started" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="..."
        exchange-pattern="request-response" />
    <logger level="INFO" message="parallel2: processing finished" />
    <flow-ref name="join" />
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="join">
    <collection-aggregator timeout="6000"
        failOnTimeout="true" />
    <combine-collections-transformer />
    <logger level="INFO"
        message="Continuing processing of: #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" />
</sub-flow>
```

EDIT: In the above config, the aggregator times out after 6 seconds. This is potentially too short for your actual use case: increase as you see fit. Also it is set to fail on time-out, which is maybe not the behaviour you desire in case not all the outbound HTTP endpoint interactions succeeded: it's up to you to decide based on your use case.

Comment: I tried you solution. But this getting struck at the "collection-aggregator". After the timout it shows the exception. I could see that both the sub-flows have returned the result.                             2012-12-31 11:40:41,604 ERROR [Pref_Flow.event.correlator] exception.AbstractExceptionListener (AbstractExceptionListener.java:296) - 
************
Message               : Correlation timed out while waiting on event group with Id: "ccc5b81c-5368-11e2-91a5-d984788f3b10". Message payload is of type: CopyOnWriteArrayList
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
------------

Comment: Exception stack is:
1. Correlation timed out while waiting on event group with Id: "ccc5b81c-5368-11e2-91a5-d984788f3b10". Message payload is of type: CopyOnWriteArrayList (org.mule.routing.correlation.CorrelationTimeoutException)
  org.mule.routing.correlation.EventCorrelator:412              Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.routing.correlation.CorrelationTimeoutException: Correlation timed out while waiting on event group with Id: "ccc5b81c-5368-11e2-91a5-d984788f3b10". org.mule.routing.correlation.EventCorrelator.handleGroupExpiry(EventCorrelator.java:412)

Comment: Not sure what the problem is: the config works perfectly fine for me. I've added an EDIT note at the end of my solution to attract your attention to the aggregator settings you may need to tune to your use case.

Comment: its working....  The problem was I have changed teh parallel "sub-flows" to "flow". This was the issue. When all the other flows except the main flow are made as sub-flows its working.   Thank you very much.

Comment: I have tried adding some INVOCATION scoped varaible in the parallel sub-flows with the idea to retrieve them in the "join" flow so that I can start using them. But what I observed is that the varailbes from only one of the paralle flows is shown in the "join" flow. And the other thing is it is always not specific which parallel flows varaibles are available. Sometime ParallelFlow1's vaiables are available sometime it is of ParallelFlow2. Please help me understand why this is happening. Is there any way that I can get all the flow varaible added in the parallel flows in my "join" flow.

Comment: The `combine-collections-transformer` combines only the payloads of the aggregated messages, not the properties. For what you want to achieve, remove it and created your own version, based on `org.mule.transformer.simple.CombineCollectionsTransformer`, that combines properties as well.